# Uniform limit of pointwise limits of continuous functions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence

Let $X$ be topological spaces, $Y$ a metric space and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions, with $f_n:X\rightarrow Y$ pointwise limit of continuous functions for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then suppose that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. My question now is:

- Under which hypothesis on $Y$ do we have that $f$ is itself pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions?

I know that the statement holds for $Y=\mathbb{R}$, and I think that it should also hold for any $Y$ finite-dimensional Banach space, but what if $Y$ is not even a TVS? Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT: the question is inspired by a lemma (Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, p. 192 Lemma 24.11) used to prove the Lebesgue Hausdorff and Banach theorem for Baire class 1 functions.